# how to add speech training data to tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, speech

I have labelled .wav files to train a Convolutional Neural Network. These are for Bengali phones, for which no standard Dataset is available. I want to input these .wav files to Tensorflow for training my CNN model. I want to create Grayscale Spectrograms from these .wav files, which will be input for my model. I need help in how to do so. If there is more than one alternative, what are their strength and weakness?

Also, they are of variable time lengths, like some are 70ms, some are 160ms. Is there a way to divide them in 20ms segments?

Comment: Can anyone provide any example with librosa and matplotlib?

Comment: I finally created grayscale spectrograms from my .wav files with 50ms duration. If anyone interested in the code i can post.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in my research.  I used the Linux utility SOX to do the audio wave file manipulation and creating spectrograms.

On the audio file length, you can use the "trim" option within SOX to split the file into 20ms segments.  Something along the lines of the following:

```
sox myaudio.wav trim 0 0.02 : newfile : restart
```

Using the "spectrogram" option of SOX, you can then create the spectrogram.

```
sox myaudio.wav -n spectrogram -m -x 256 -y 256 -o myspectrogram.png
```

The command will create a monochrome spectrogram of size 256x256 and store it in the file "myspectrogram.png".

In my research, I did not split the file into smaller chunks.  I found that using the whole wave file of the word was sufficient to get good recognition.  But, it depends on what your long term goal is.

Comment: Thank you. One problem solved. Now, this myspectrogram.png needs to be converted into TFRecord or something like that to be an input to tensorflow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at the ffmpeg ops in TensorFlow for loading audio files, though we don't yet have a built-in spectrogram:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/ffmpeg

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look and then will be back.

Comment: If i am not mistaken in ffmpeg_lib.h its noted as
 "// Reads an audio file using ffmpeg and converts it into an array of samples in
// [-1.0, 1.0]. If there are multiple channels in the audio then each frame will
// contain a separate sample for each channel. Frames are ordered by time."
So, it will represent waveform and not spectrogram.